# Is there a way to know what happens at command prompt when we copy and paste a file from one location to another?

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to know what happens at command prompt when we copy and paste a file from one location to another? I.e. I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy and paste a file from one location to another then there must be some commands executed at backend to do the following process, right?

Comment: Do you mean like in a GUI file manager? What OS? There are library calls and system calls; copying does not have to be performed with something you could type in a command prompt (shell). If you attach a debugger to whatever program you're thinking about then you may be able to see what happens under the hood. Also please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is. If you want to know the commands because you think they will solve some other problem then it may be better to ask about that problem in the first place.

Comment: Hi, I want to copy paste one file from Host window to Remote desktop using cmd only but while doing so and using the commands like xcopy and robocopy, it says access is denied but when i use ctrl + C & ctrl + V manually in the GUI it works fine ( like regular copy pasting is working but not through the command prompt).